# Displaying WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) coordinate grid over EPSG:3857 map in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, wgs84, epsg

Is there a way to either display a grid with WGS 84 decimal degrees over a map that is in EPSG:3857, something like OpenStreetMap? I've tried changing the project's the map's and the grid's CRS but I either get a map that's stretched and has wrong coordinates, no map or when I tried changing grid CRS no grid at all.

Also, what's with the coordinates being reversed in QGIS?

Comment: Yes there is. You don't need to change any CRSs, QGIS will handle the transformations [on-the-fly](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_projections/working_with_projections.html#:~:text=an%20NTv2%20transformation-,10.6.%20Datum%20Transformations,of%20possible%20transforms%20available%20to%20reproject%20to%20the%20project%E2%80%99s%20CRS!,-By%20default%2C%20QGIS). Simply add your layers to your canvas and then add a Grid to the map layout and choose WGS84 as its CRS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two approaches to create a grid: in the QGIS main window, creating a vector (line) layer or in the print composer. Normally, you should stick to the last solution. However, if for some reason you need it as a separate layer, I describe both approaches:

**QGIS main map canvas**

To add a grid in the QGIS main windon on the map canvas, go to Menu Vector > Research Tools > Create Grid. Use Line Grid Type, set Grid CRS to `EPSG:4326` and define a `Grid extent` consisting of integer numbers only - like `-189,189,-134,128 [EPSG:4326]`. For Horizontal/Vertical spacing use an integer value like `1` as well for 1 degrees intervals.

Depending on the project CRS, you should densify the grid lines to get a correct grid.

[image]

**Print composer**

To add a grid in the print composer, on the map element's Item Properties, expand the section `Grid` click the green plus to create a new grid and make the relevant settings:

[image]